# Building C++ project with MSBuild does not resolve relative includes

Tags: c++, msbuild

I'm trying to build a c++ project with an msbuild command line.

The command is as follows:

`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" MyProjectDll.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64`

The build fails with the following error:

**fatal  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Common/SecureApp/SecApp/Sdk.hpp': No such file or directory**

When I open the file that causes the error, the code is as following:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "Common/SecureApp/SecApp/Sdk.hpp"                                                                                  
#include "Common/SecureApp/CppTools/Payload.h"
```

The include path that starts with "Common/..." is relative to the file it is referenced from.
When building the project through the Visual Studio it works fine.
What param should I add to Msbuild to make it work as well?

The whole project is full with relative references in this convention, so I prefer not to replace all of them to another convention.

Thanks